# Want to send cloud-formation output through an email

Tags: amazon-web-services, powershell, aws-cloudformation, devops, aws-cloudformation-custom-resource

I am writing a cloud-formation template where I am running two powershell scripts. Now I want to fetch the output of both the scripts and want to send that to an email which is already mentioned in cloud-formation parameter.

here is the code:-

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Description: Test Document
Resources:  
    Type: AWS::SSM::Document
    Properties:
      DocumentType: Command
      Name: "Test Upgrade"
      Content: 
        schemaVersion: '2.2'
        description: "Test Upgrade"
        parameters:
          Emails:
            type: String
            description: |- 
              enter the email address to send the overall output
        mainSteps:
          - action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
            name: "DriverUpgrade"
            precondition:
              StringEquals: ["platformType", "Windows"]
            inputs:
              runCommand:
[]
            timeoutSeconds: 3600
            onFailure: Continue
            maxAttempts: 1
            isCritical: False
            nextStep: Second Driver
          - action: "aws:runPowerShellScript"
            name: "SecondDriverUpgrade"
            precondition:
              StringEquals: ["platformType", "Windows"]
            inputs:
              runCommand:
[]
            timeoutSeconds: 3600
            onFailure: Continue
            isCritical: False
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use AWS CLI command 'ses send-email' inside the Powershell script or as a part of Run Command parameters?
Certainly you have to configure the SES service beforehand in cfn template or console.

You could retrieve the email address from parameter store by using AWS CLI command ssm get-parameters.

To store the output of the scripts you could use a local file, parameter store, or, for example, dynamodb table etc.

https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ses/send-email.html
https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ssm/get-parameters.html

Comment: But how do I collect the output of these two powershell scripts that i am running ?? And how will i fetch the email that I am passing in parameters.

Comment: @shubhamkamboj Please see amended answer.

Comment: Thanks for your reply Marko, Just want to clear that the parameter we want to use to send email is in cloud-formation itself (parameters: Emails:) whatever email we have in this we want to send the output on that email. second we can attach the out put but that must be in Json format. So if you can mention those steps in formation template that would be really help full for me.